# how to find location by sending an sms to a specific number linked with a web server or to an android app?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, java-me

I am going to make an application in which I want to get the user location through sms i.e a person sends an sms to a specific number linked with a web server or to an android app and from that sms I want to find his/her location. This should be done without installing any application as I want to use this feature for old mobiles like nokia 3310 which don't support java. Please give suggestions. Languages I'll be using for my app are php, android, java.

Comment: Ask them their postal code. No other way to find their location.

Comment: FBI, NSA, CIA or any other I dont know name might CBI LOL

Answer (score 3):

Whichever cellular service provider you are working with will give you an API that you can use to communicate with their database mapping IMEI numbers to specific cell towers.

Comment: Example? I didn't know such thing. Very interesting.

Comment: is that true.?please provide more detaisl

Comment: @sarnold will you please elaborate your answer or more specifically provide any example or link

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't find the location from sended/receiving SMS on both Android and Java ME application.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not install any application then who will return location on device end ??

Not possible until device support location - based -service and an app is installed which will give location to server .

Answer (score 0):

I was having a project back in the day. It was not the same, but kinda give you ideas of why this is not being done on non-carrier side.

In short, cell phone will comunicate to a cell tower(or cell site) constantly via a control channel so the system knows your cell's location. sending an sms is kinda same. But unless you work with a carrier, chances you get an API from them to read the package via a control channel is ZERO. So you are in no hope if you are not one of them.

Here is an idea of what you can do:

1. You can have a background service that's running to get a
   callback when location changed.
2. get the lat and long from location callback to the service.
3. detect and check the target number when user sends out
   sms [here is the link](http://gbandroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/MobileSpy/src/org/ddth/android/monitor/observer/AndroidSmsWatcher.java)
4. if you detect the target number is your
   server's number, just add the lat and lon to the sms message body.
5. then do whatever your want with that sms data.

I hope This could help.